# Azure AD B2C - custom sign up page, email verification

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In the standard Azure B2C sign up experience there's a button *Send verification code* which sends a code to a provided email. But I'm creating a custom sign up page (because the system admin has to approve users) and I wonder if I can use the Azure built-in sending verification code. Can I do that? Or is it just easier to implement myself considering I'll need to customize email body and probably sender's address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your own custom sign-up page, outside of Azure AD B2C, then you cannot use the email verification feature of Azure AD B2C.

The standard Azure AD B2C policies support some email customization through Azure AD's [company branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding), but complete customization (including changing sender's address) is not currently supported.